# Updating WCF service with new methods for different client

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I tried searching if this is already asked or not but honestly I got confused about search keywords for this.... therefore I am asking this here.

Lets say I have developed a WCF service which is used by around 100 clients and then a new group of client comes and they want the service too with some additional methods in the existing service.

What should be the approach for this?

Comment: Are you asking to **lock it down** so that only the new clients could access these _new_ methods?  Otherwise see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142813/adding-methods-to-the-webservice-do-old-clients-need-to-update-web-references

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only **add** new operations to your service, all your existing clients will be fine.

A similar question:

- *[Does adding a method to a WCF ServiceContract break existing clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631935/does-adding-a-method-to-a-wcf-servicecontract-break-existing-clients)*